# I don't want to see everything in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, get

```
function date(day, month, year) {
  month += "";
  if (month.length <= 1) 
    month = "0" + month;

  document.location.href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?page=events&day="
                         + day + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year;
}
```

I made this function with help of a Youtube video, problem is, i don't want to see the date i selected in the URL. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: you can't. you're redirecting, which is a get, which means you have to pass all parameters in the url, which means the date has to be there.

Comment: is there any way i can change the function so i don't have to pass all parameters in the URL?

Comment: how should I know? You haven't explained what this script is doing on the server, but one way or another, if that daystring/etc... is required, then they're going to have to be passed SOMEHOW.

Comment: could you explain what you intend to do with this code then I might give some better suggestions.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to stackoverflow, it's simply a calendar, if i click a certain date this date should be the new date selected, right now the selected date is taken from the URL, but i would like to so this through a method like POST instead of GET, which is currently used. i have tried changing everything to post but that pretty much just destroys the calendar.

Comment: did the answer helped?

Comment: edit the functions code here and paste which you are using right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?page=events";?>" method="post" id="calender-form">
     <input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?php echo $_POST['day'];?>"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php echo $_POST['month'];?>"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $_POST['year'];?>"/>
</form>
```

And in your function date() instead of:

```
document.location.href=......
```

Do this:

```
var calenderForm=document.getElementById("calender-form");
calenderForm.day.value=daystring;
calenderForm.month.value=monthstring;
calenderForm.year.value=year;
calenderForm.submit;
}
```

Replace $_GET with $_POST. Try this it should work. If you have problems, add it in the comment. If it helps you mark is as answer and vote it. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to implement that just now, and now my code seems to do the right thing when inspecting the element in my browser, but the selected date isn't shown... which should happen by comparing every date in the table, which is the set up for the calendar, with the date given by the link, which is the current date when arriving at the calendar page

Comment: i've edited some thing in the action attribute review it once

Comment: to be honest, i don't know if i have placed the form correctly, this should be in the call for the function right? i think i'm being stupid at the moment... my current piece of code using the function date() is as follows:<td <?php if ($thisDay == $selectedDate)
                              {
                                  echo "class='active'";
                              } else {
                                  echo "class='date'";
                              }
                              ?> height='75px' onclick="date(<?php echo $daystring. "," . $monthstring . "," . $year ?>)"

Comment: <td onclick="date(<?php echo $daystring. "," . $monthstring . "," . $year ?>)" sorry, pressed enter and couldn't edit any further...

Comment: you can place the form anywhere you like but do it a the last of the page right before `</body>`

Comment: okay moved the form, what do i do with the onclick? sorry, that must sound like a very stupid question..

Comment: try surrounding the strings in quotes. i often have issues with them